# use another useeffect result in another

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, use-effect

New react developer here, here i have two useEffects, one of them(first one) is an object which contains a 'name' which i want to use in my second useEffect. Second useEffect contains an array of objects, these array of objects has 'billingName' and 'driverName', some of them has same value in them for example driverName: "james". What i want to do is in my second useEffect check if 'name' from first useEffect is same as 'driverName', only then do this 'setOrders(res);
setRenderedData(res);'

my error message: Property 'driverName' does not exist on type...

my object: {
id: "98s7faf",
isAdmin: true,
name: "james"}

my array:  [{billingName: "trump",driverName: "james"}, {billingName: "putin",driverName: "alex"}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

my code:

```js
 const [driver, setDriver] = useState<User>();

useEffect(() => {
    
    api.userApi
      .apiUserGet()
      .then((res: React.SetStateAction<User | undefined>) => {
        console.log(res);
        setDriver(res);
      });
  }, [api.userApi]);


 useEffect(() => {
    
    api.caApi
      .apiCaGet(request)
      .then((res: React.SetStateAction<CaDto[] | undefined>) => {
        if (driver?.name == res?.driverName) {
          setOrders(res);
          setRenderedData(res);
          console.log(res);
        }
      });
  }, [api.caApi]);
```

Comment: You can call `api.caApi` in `then` of `api.userApi`

Comment: the error seems to be coming from your API result, rather than from your `driver` state.

Comment: No, its cuz of comparing array with string

Answer (score 0):

You can call api.caApi in then of api.userApi,

```
 useEffect(() => {
  api.userApi.apiUserGet().then((res1?: User ) => {
  setDriver(res1);
  return api.caApi.apiCaGet(request).then((res?: CaDto[]) 
  => {
    if (res.some(({ driverName }) => driverName === res1?.name)) {
      setOrders(res);
      setRenderedData(res);
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
});
}, [api.caApi, api.userApi]);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231767/discussion-on-answer-by-arpit-bhalla-use-another-useeffect-result-in-another).